# Threading in DNN6 module

Tags: asp.net, multithreading, email, dotnetnuke

I can't find anything on threading in Dot Net Nuke online. I need to have a timer in a module that attaches to a site that sends out emails automatically so many days before an event based on the alert days and event date in a database. I have sent emails in other parts of the module code and have done threading on a site that is fully coded for another company recently but with simply being a module on dot net nuke I need to know how to do the threading so that an email sending thread can check dates and send emails daily. I am programming the modules in asp.net/C#

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is a DNN Scheduler. http://dotnetslackers.com/Community/blogs/kaushalparik/archive/2010/05/11/how-to-create-dotnetnuke-dnn-scheduler.aspx